# Using Curl to Automate Upload Files to ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, curl

I am trying to use cURL to automate some deployment tasks to an ASP.NET Application. But I am having some problems with it. The login part works perfectly but i guess the application for some reason has some sort of control for this kind of tools. These application was developed or an external company(real crappy app). Basically what i need to do is upload every month like 10 xml files by hand which is stupid!. I want to be able to automate this by using my own script(like ruby) and call cURL on the background to process the http requests.

*Does any one know about any problems using cURL and an ASP.NET app?.  May be should I write my own C# tool for this?.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with curl and ASP.NET. curl speaks HTTP and offers many different features and ways to send data, including multiport formpost uploads etc. You most likely just haven't figured out exactly how to mimic a browser when doing your command lines.

Comment: One of the reasons of the asp.net html is that there is a lot of crap within the html document. I guess i have to figure out.